# How to make row number dynamic in Excel VLOOKUP

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to figure out how to make the row number portion of my VLOOKUP formula to be generated based on the current row of the cell holding the formula.

```
=VLOOKUP(D209|M196:O372|2|FALSE)
```

So in the above, the first parameter is 'D209'. I want the '209' to be generated dynamically based on the current row.

I can get it with

```
=ROW()
```

But when I try to combine the two it breaks :(

```
=VLOOKUP(D=ROW|M196:O372|2|FALSE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
=VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("D"&ROW())|M196:O372|2|FALSE)
```

Gotta use INDIRECT()